# Using GPU train model but PyTorch throws the " CUDA out of memory"

Tags: python-3.x

OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 3.52 GiB (GPU 5; 10.76 GiB total capacity; 6.03 GiB already allocated; 3.34 GiB free; 6.24 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

Hi all! I have enough GPU memory，But I run code get the following error.

Is there any great god who can give me some advice?